# Should we consider the cases of absolute value before or after differentiating?

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, absolute-value

Consider some function: $\DeclareMathOperator{argmin}{argmin}$

$$f(w) = \underset{w}{\argmin}\:(z-w)^2 + \lambda\gamma |w|\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:where\:\lambda,\gamma\in\mathbb{R}^+$$

I'm quite confused when dealing with functions containing absolute value terms for the purposes of differentiation (w.r.t $w$). In some cases, I've seen people differentiate the function *including* the absolute value terms *first*; resulting in:

$${f}'(w) = 2(w-z) + \lambda\gamma\frac{w}{|w|}$$

and *then* considering the 2 cases where:

$$w\in\mathbb{R}^+$$ $$w\in\mathbb{R}^-$$

Meanwhile, I've also seen the case where people would consider the cases *first* (notice the inclusion of zero):

$$w\in\mathbb{R}^+_0$$ $$w\in\mathbb{R}^-_0$$

resulting in:

$${f}(w) = (z-w)^2 + \lambda\gamma w$$

$${f}(w) = (z-w)^2 - \lambda\gamma w$$

respectively, and *then* differentiating results in:

$${f}'(w) = 2(w-z) + \lambda\gamma$$

$${f}'(w) = 2(w-z) - \lambda\gamma$$

respectively.

For me there's a subtle difference in that the second way, $w=0$ *can* be a solution, whereas in the first way it would've been undefined. Sorry if I'm understanding this incorrectly but could someone shed some light on this issue please?

Comment: In the second case, what happens when you plug in $w=0$? What is the value of the derivative? Is it the same for both pieces?

Comment: @Tyberius well for $w=0$, one piece would be $-2z+\lambda \gamma$, while the other one would be $-2z-\lambda \gamma$, so does that imply the first way is more appropriate?

Comment: I think they both give the same result. The first case makes it a little more explicit that $f'(0)$ is undefined, but the derivative is also undefined for the second case. At zero, those functions aren't really giving you the derivative, but rather [semi-derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability) or left/right derivatives. If these aren't equal at some point, then the function isn't differentiable at that point. A more to the point example would be $g(x)=|x|$: in either way of calculating the derivative you find that $g'(0)$ can't be properly defined.

Comment: @Tyberius The concept of semi-derivatives (which I've never come across before) makes it clear now. I saw the second way being used in ML and I guess the intuition there was to have some semi-derivatives at least such that one can pragmatically program it. If you could put your comment as an answer to that I could mark it!

Comment: The notion of [subderivatives/subdifferentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative) helps deal with functions like the absolute value function in the context of optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though both methods lead to $f'(0)$ being undefined. The first case makes this a little more explicit, since you it has a division by zero, but the second case also can't define a derivative at that point. The derivatives of each of the pieces of your function give inconsistent results for $w=0$:
$$\lim_{a\to0^-}f'(a)=2z-\lambda\gamma$$
$$\lim_{a\to0^+}f'(a)=2z+\lambda\gamma$$

If the left/right derivatives (or [semi-derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability)) at a point aren't equal, then the function is not differentiable at that point.

This same issue arises if you just look at $g(x)=|x|$: no matter how you calculate it, splitting it into pieces before or after taking the derivative, its clear that the derivative is undefined at $x=0$, as the left and right derivatives aren't equal. Geometrically, you can see this from the sharp point at $x=0$ in a plot of $|x|$.